# Soomla In App purchase going through store but GetItemBalance returning 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, store, release, soomla

I am making an app for iOS using unity. I am using Soomla store to implement in app purchases. Everything was working in test flight. The app was submitted for review and was accepted. Now when downloading from the app store. The in app purchases work and have debited money from my account and give a success message. The content is being hidden using

```
if (StoreInventory.GetItemBalance(category.storeId) >= 1)
{
}
```

And is not showing. It was before in test flight.

So the items are not being added to the store. I have checked test flight again with a different build and that is now behaving in the same way. The purchase going through with all the messages as expected, but no item in the store. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: I stopped using Soomla and started using unity3d's IAP assits.